# Logic for getting number of pages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If a page can have 27 items printed on it and number of items can be any positive number then how can I find number of pages if I have number of items, I tried Modulus and division but didn't helped.

FYI, I am using C# as programming platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, isn't the answer just the number of total items divided by $27$ and then rounded up?

If you had $54$ total items, $54/27=2$ pages, which doesn't need to round.

If you had $100$ total items, $100/27=3.7$ which rounds up to $4$ pages.

If you had 115 total items, $115/27=4.26$ which rounds up to $5$ pages.

Comment: In C#, that translates as [`Math.Ceil(items / 27.0)`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6020695#6020695).

Comment: Or to `items / 27 + (items % 27 > 0 ? 1 : 0)` if you wish to avoid the Math library.

Comment: I program in Java, so I'm not sure if they have this in C# where you truncate a number by converting it into an integer. In that case you can add .5 to your answer and truncate it, that would be the easiest way without the Math library.

Comment: @mathguy, this just rounds a number; it needs to be rounded up.

Comment: @zneak I totally lost track of the problem. Thanks. =P

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood you correct. Assume you have int "items" that express the quantity of items to be printed.

wholePages expresses how much whole pages will be printed, totalPages tells on how many pages you will print something. "totalPages" is calculated in easy way; it can be made shorter

int wholePages = items / 27;
int totalPages = items / 27 + ( items % 27 > 0 ? 1 : 0 );